# Fill in null values using previous value using FIRST_VALUE or LAST_VALUE

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having a problem with filling in blank values using previous not null values.
I have tried using the FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE formula, but I dont quite manage to get the desired results.

Here is an query with example data and what I have been trying to do.

```
WITH test_data AS  (
SELECT 'A10-79' AS target_group, '2020w1' AS week, 'TV' AS placement, 10.1 AS views UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL,  '2020w2', 'TV', 0.3 UNION ALL 
SELECT Null,  '2020w3', 'TV', 4.3 UNION ALL 
SELECT Null,  '2020w4', 'TV', 5.1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A40-79', '2020w1', 'TV', 7.1 AS views UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL,  '2020w2', 'TV', 0.1 UNION ALL 
SELECT Null,  '2020w3', 'TV', 2.3 UNION ALL 
SELECT Null,  '2020w4', 'TV', 3.1
)

SELECT 
FIRST_VALUE(target_group IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY week ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
AND CURRENT ROW) AS target_group,
week,
placement, 
views 
FROM test_data
```

And this produces this result

[image]

And this is what I would like to get

[image]

The problem is that I cant seem to find a way where it will fill in just the blanks with the previous or first value, and not overwrite every field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would try to improve your source data, as it is unlikely you can guarantee that unlabeled data would always be in the proper order.

However, in the spirit of answering the question, please consider the following:

```
WITH test_data AS  (
SELECT 'A10-79' AS target_group, '2020w1' AS week, 'TV' AS placement, 10.1 AS views UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL,  '2020w2', 'TV', 0.3 UNION ALL 
SELECT Null,  '2020w3', 'TV', 4.3 UNION ALL 
SELECT Null,  '2020w4', 'TV', 5.1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A40-79', '2020w1', 'TV', 7.1 AS views UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL,  '2020w2', 'TV', 0.1 UNION ALL 
SELECT Null,  '2020w3', 'TV', 2.3 UNION ALL 
SELECT Null,  '2020w4', 'TV', 3.1
),
temp1 as (
    -- Let's add a row id since the source table has no underlying indication of ordering
    select *, row_number() over() as my_rn from test_data
),
temp2 as (
    -- Let's create some separation between the target groups
    select
        *,
        sum(case when target_group is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by my_rn) as my_partition
    from temp1
)
-- Now we can fill in the missing values
select
    first_value(target_group ignore nulls) over (partition by my_partition order by my_rn) as target_group,
    week, 
    placement, 
    views
from temp2
order by 1,2
```